# Why am I getting a NullPointerException on this line?

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception, sharedpreferences

My code which previously worked fine, is now throwing a NPE. It's not on a new line either so I am pretty confused. Can someone point me in the right direction?

The problem line is identified about half way down.

```
public class FavouritesActivity extends Activity {

private String mFavourites;
ArrayAdapter <String> adapter;
List<String> list;

private ListView lv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_favourites);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.My_Favourites);

    SharedPreferences preferences = this.getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    list = new ArrayList<String>();         
    Map<String, ?> prefsMap = preferences.getAll();
    for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry: prefsMap.entrySet()) {
        list.add(entry.getValue().toString());   //THIS IS THE PROBLEM <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    } 

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list); 

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

     lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
            // setting onItemLongClickListener and passing the position to the function
                      @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int position, long arg3) {
                String mFavourites =(lv.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
                removeItemFromList(position);   

                return true;
            }
        });

}

     protected void removeItemFromList(int position) {


            final int deletePosition = position;

            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    FavouritesActivity.this);

            alert.setTitle("Delete");
            alert.setMessage("Do you want delete this item?");
            alert.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TOD O Auto-generated method stub

                        // main code on after clicking yes
                        list.remove(deletePosition);

                        Operator();


                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();


                }
            });
            alert.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });


            alert.show();


        }

 protected void Operator() {
     SharedPreferences preferences = this.getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

        editor.remove(mFavourites);
        editor.commit();

    }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_supplements, menu);
    return true;
}   
}
```

Here is the LogCat:

```
01-10 14:08:59.850: E/AndroidRuntime(2194): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-10 14:08:59.850: E/AndroidRuntime(2194): Process: com.LifeSchematics.msg, PID: 2194
01-10 14:08:59.850: E/AndroidRuntime(2194): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.LifeSchematics.msg/com.LifeSchematics.msg.FavouritesActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-10 14:08:59.850: E/AndroidRuntime(2194):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
01-10 14:08:59.850: E/AndroidRuntime(2194):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
01-10 14:08:59.850: E/AndroidRuntime(2194):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
01-10 14:08:59.850: E/AndroidRuntime(2194):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
01-10 14:08:59.850: E/AndroidRuntime(2194):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-10 14:08:59.850: E/AndroidRuntime(2194):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-10 14:08:59.850: E/AndroidRuntime(2194):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
01-10 14:08:59.850: E/AndroidRuntime(2194):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-10 14:08:59.850: E/AndroidRuntime(2194):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-10 14:08:59.850: E/AndroidRuntime(2194):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
01-10 14:08:59.850: E/AndroidRuntime(2194):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
01-10 14:08:59.850: E/AndroidRuntime(2194):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-10 14:08:59.850: E/AndroidRuntime(2194): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-10 14:08:59.850: E/AndroidRuntime(2194):     at com.LifeSchematics.msg.FavouritesActivity.onCreate(MySupplementsActivity.java:40)
01-10 14:08:59.850: E/AndroidRuntime(2194):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
01-10 14:08:59.850: E/AndroidRuntime(2194):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-10 14:08:59.850: E/AndroidRuntime(2194):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
```

Comment: That line can't throw a `NPE`. Try cleaning your project and post the logcat.

Comment: @codeMagic I tried the clean straight away but no luck. I've added the logcat. Thanks for your time!

Comment: And you are saying that line 40 is, `adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);`?

Comment: Jeez, its obviously been a long day. No, line 40 is list.add(entry.getValue().toString());

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get NullPointerException because some preference values were stored as null and entry.getValue() is null.
So add null checking before calling toString()

```
for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry: prefsMap.entrySet()) {
    final Object value = entry.getValue();
    list.add(value == null ? "null" : value.toString());
}
```

Or

```
for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry: prefsMap.entrySet()) {
    final Object value = entry.getValue();
    if (value != null) {
        list.add(value.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: If a preference was never initialized, how can it even exist in the SharedPreferences? How would it know that preference is intended (by the programmer) to exist? Is this the result of using XML preferences without having changed them yet?

Comment: @Tenfour04 good point. The proper way of saying this would be "some preference values were stored as null".

Comment: Ah, OK. Didn't know you could store null values.